# Find executable files recursively

Tags: find, executable, command, recursive

I have got the directory called `Test` and a few directories inside it. Both `Test` and the directories inside it have executable files. I'd like to print them with `ls`. I'd use this command.

```
ls -l `find Test/ -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x -type f`
```

Is this a good/right/quick command or not?

**My solution is:**

```
find Test/ -executable -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

and got the same result as *warl0ck* and *pradeepchhetri* offered.

Comment: You might want to check my updates ...

Comment: try `find ... -exec -ls -l {} \+` instead of `\;` - doing that will cause only one `ls` command to be generated with multiple filename args, similar to how `xargs` works.  read the `find` man page and search for `-exec` for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really, you can integrate the ls command with find,

`find Test/ -type f -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x -exec ls -l {} \;`

**UPDATE**

Actually `-executable` is not an equivalent of `-perm /u=x,g=x,o=x`. You might have files that is executable only by the group or others, which will not be displayed.

So, depends on your purpose, if you want files executable only by you, that's okay to use `-executable`.

Comment: thanks. After I have gotten over 15 reputation, I'll vote up.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use `-exec`, as `find` comes with a `-ls` flag.

```
$ find Test/ -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x -type f -ls
```

From the `man` page:

> -ls    True;  list  current file in ls -dils format on standard output. The block counts are of 1K blocks, unless the environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, in which case 512-byte blocks are used.  See the UNUSUAL FILENAMES section for information about how unusual characters in filenames are handled.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `-exec` argument of find command.

```
$ find Test/ -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Comment: thanks. I'll vote up your answer later. Now I don't have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Find files that are executable by the *current* login user

```
[sudo] find /path -type f -executable
```

or to find if executable bit sets for at least one of the Owner/Group/Other:

```
[sudo] find /path -type f -perm /111
```

or executable only to *owner*:

```
[sudo] find /path -type f -perm /100
```

or

```
[sudo] find /path -type f -perm -100
```