# Find all executable files excluding certain directories

Tags: bash, find, executable

I'm looking to find all executable files that are NOT in my `$PATH`.

Currently I'm doing this

```
find / \( -path "/opt" -prune -o -path "/var" -prune -o -path "/bin" -prune -o -path "/sbin" -prune -o -path "/usr" -prune -o -path "/opt" \) -o -type f -executable -exec file {} \;
```

I feel like there is a better way, I tried using a for loop with `IFS=:` to separate out the different parts of `PATH` but couldn't get it to work.

Edit: I should have specified I don't want to use a script for this.

Comment: executable by the current login-ed user?  see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622761/72456

Comment: If you don't want a script, what do you want?

Comment: A 1 liner, no matter how complicated. Figured my method wasn't the simplest way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming GNU `find` and the `bash` shell (as is used in the question), this is a short script that would accomplish what you're trying to do:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=:
set -f

args=( -false )
for dirpath in $PATH; do
        args+=( -o -path "$dirpath" )
done

find / \( \( "${args[@]}" \) -o \
          \( -type d \( ! -executable -o ! -readable \) \) \) -prune -o \
    -type f -executable -exec file {} +
```

This first creates the array `args`, consisting of dynamically constructed arguments to `find`. It does this by splitting the value of `$PATH` on colons, the value that we've given to the `IFS` variable.  The splitting is happening when we use `$PATH` unquoted in the loop header.

Ordinarily, the shell would invoke filename globbing on each of the words generated from the splitting of `$PATH`, but I'm using `set -f` to turn off filename globbing, just in case any of the directory paths in `$PATH` contains globbing characters (these would still be problematic as the `-path` operand of `find` would interpret them as patterns).

If my `PATH` variable contains the string

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

then `args` will be the following list (each line here is a separate element in the array, this is not really a set of strings with newline characters in-between them):

```
-false
-o
-path
/usr/bin
-o
-path
/bin
-o
-path
/usr/sbin
-o
-path
/sbin
-o
-path
/usr/X11R6/bin
-o
-path
/usr/local/bin
-o
-path
/usr/local/sbin
```

This list is slotted into the `find` command invocation, in parentheses.  There is no need to repeat `-prune` for each and every directory, as you could just use it once as I have above.

I've opted for pruning any non-executable or non-readable directory.  This ought to get rid of a lot of permission errors for directories that you can't access or list the contents of.  Would you want to simplify the `find` command by removing this bit, use

```bsh
find / \( "${args[@]}" \) -prune -o \
    -type f -executable -exec file {} +
```

Also, I'm running `file` on the found pathnames in batches, rather than once per pathname.

Comment: Note that executable but not readable files would not be reported.

Comment: Note that it assumes that `$PATH` components don't contain wildcard characters (unlikely to be a problem in practice).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This is why I used `set -f`. Also, I should add the assumption about not wanting to see non-readable executables.

Comment: With or without `-f`, with a `PATH='*'`;  `-path '*'` would match any path.

Comment: Note that the second `-executable` is redundant.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for that heads up about `*`. I think I sorted out avoiding problematic directories now.

Comment: That also assumes `$PATH` doesn't contain relative paths. In practice, that's usually limited to `.` or `""`. You'd probably want to exclude though (and revert my edit)

Comment: Another potential problem is with `$PATH` components that are symlinks (not so uncommon in practice). You could switch to `zsh` and loop over `${(u)path:P}`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Or use `find -L`?

Comment: No `find -L` wouldn't work reliably here. For instance if you have `/usr` -> `/` symlink, `find` would not descend into `/usr` to avoid the loop, and even  if it did and prune `/usr/bin`, it would still not prune `/bin` (same as `/usr/bin`).

Comment: I should have specified I don't want to use a script!

Comment: Given that this is [tag:bash], we can replace the loop with something like `paths=($PATH); args=(-false ${paths[@]/#/-o -path })`.  Oh, that doesn't quite work, because `-o -path foo` becomes a single string in the array - can that be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
set -o extendedglob
LC_ALL=C find / -regextype egrep \
  -regex ${(j[|])${(u)path:P}//(#m)[][.\$^*()+{}\\|.]/\\$MATCH} -prune -o \
  -type f -executable -exec file {} +
```

- `$path` is a special array *tied* to the `$PATH` env var.
- `$path:P` gets the realpath (absolute, canonical, without symlinks) of each member
- `${(u)array}` removes duplicate (here after canonicalisation)
- `${array//(#m)pattern/\\$MATCH}` prepends a `\` before anything that matches the `pattern` (here all the egrep regexp operators)
- `${(j[|])array}` joins the elements of the array with `|` to obtain a `/dir|/dir\.2|...` regexp.